# How to skip page if request response is 404 in R?

Tags: r, rvest

I'm scraping a website and getting 404 error. I use tryCatch() but it doesn't work. How can I skip this page/url using it or any method you can suggest?

```
result = tryCatch(expr = {
  map_dfr(
    .x = url,
    .f = function(x) {
      tibble(
        #expr
      )
    }
  )
  
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the `tryCatch`, you can specify `error` and if it goes into error, which value to return.  In the code, I didn't find that part.  May be you have tried, not sure?

Comment: I think that the more scalable approach is to use `function_safely = purrr::safely(function(etc))` and then use `map_dfr` on `function_safely`. The outcome provides two lists: one for errors and one for results. To select just the working part, call `outcome$result`

Comment: I was wondering how I could run tryCatch() method and put error function so, it works! Thanks! @akrun

Comment: @nerdakgul you may check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r)

Comment: I've learned another function. Thanks! @p0bs

Comment: I thought I would not put this function because it's optional @akrun